# adding string in List and obtaining it C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to store string to list every time i Click a button.
So far I did,

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();
private void Button_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   data.Add("Some string value");
}
```

I want 3 string value if I click button 3 time in a list.

Comment: Ok, what's wrong with current code? what you are expecting?

Comment: everytime i click the button, new list is created and only single string is stored in the "data"

Comment: you are storing this so far everytime you click the button `Some string value` what is the problem and or issue.. you expect us to be able to read your mind..?

Comment: Where did you declare `List<string> data = new List<string>();`. Is it a global variable?

Comment: impossible that a new list is created based on what you have posted unless you have the data object that's creating the new instance inside of the Button Click event..

Comment: @BikramLimbu: No, the code that you showed will not create new List, which will create the new List only when the declaration of `data` is inside the `Button_Click`

Comment: The code you posted will not behave as you describe. Please either post the real code that you have a problem with, or spend some time creating a simple example that demonstrates the problem (and run it to make sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `static` keyword , working code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static List<string> data = new List<string>();
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
           new Program().addelements();
           new Program().addelements();

           for(int i=0; i<data.Count;i++)
            Console.WriteLine(data[i]);
        }

        private  void addelements()
        {
           data.Add("Some string value");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it's not direct answer, because the questions is not correct, but I think it will help him

Comment: wrong..! you cannot use `data` like this, need to specify the class

Comment: Ofcourse it can be static but you have to use, `myClassName.data` instead for just `data` otherwise the code won't compile

Comment: maybe i was unable to explain the problem clearly but this answer helped

Comment: It's just for example :)

Comment: I didn't   make addelementsfor  static  for showing that from static context you can call none static methods